# Sending push messages to all users using GCM

Tags: php, android, mysql, push-notification

I am trying to send a push message to all android users of my application. I am able to send only to one user and unable to send to all.

Here is my code :

**PUSH.php**

```
<?php
// API access key from Google API's Console
define( 'API_ACCESS_KEY', 'my api key');

$registrationIds = array( 'user_push_id');


$msg = array
(
    'URL'   => 'http://www.apple.com/in/',
    'message'   => 'Did you like it ???',
    'image' =>'http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/dan-wiersma/apple-tv/128/Apple-Logo-icon.png'
);

$fields = array
(
    'registration_ids'  => $registrationIds,
    'data'          => $msg
);

$headers = array
(
    'Authorization: key=' . API_ACCESS_KEY,
    'Content-Type: application/json'
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_URL, 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send' );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );
$result = curl_exec($ch );
curl_close( $ch );
echo $result;
?>
```

please help me getting all the users from mysql table as below:

```
$sth = mysqli_query("SELECT PUSH_ME from push_msg_android");
$registrationIds = array();
while($r = mysqli_fetch_array($sth)) {
    $registrationIds['PUSH_ID'] = $r;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to send a push notification to several users, you need to fill the `registrationIds` array with all users' registration ids.

In the end, it should look like this if you have 3 users:

```
[78475826748590, 74648598273895, 85737485957849]
```

In your case, it means replace this line:

```
$registrationIds = array( 'user_push_id');
```

by:

```
$result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT PUSH_ID from push");
$registrationIds = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
   $registrationIds[] = $row[0];
}
```

This is assuming that your users registration ids are stored in the column `PUSH_ID` of the table `push` of your database.

In a more normal setting, where your users' registration ids would be stored in a column `push_notification_id` in a table `users`, the query should be:

```
$result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT push_notification_id from users");
$registrationIds = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
   $registrationIds[] = $row[0];
}
```

You will also need to create the `$db` object before, to create the connection to the database. For example :

```
$db = mysqli_connect("localhost","my_user","my_password","my_db");
```

Comment: getting this error......................{"multicast_id":6112092832428284343,"success":0,"failure":2,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"InvalidRegistration"},{"error":"InvalidRegistration"}]}

Comment: well no it is not working the same error as before:  {"multicast_id":6112092832428284343,"success":0,"fail‌​ure":2,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"InvalidRegistration"},{"error":"Inv‌​alidRegistration"}]}

Comment: thanks for this i got the message on one device but not on the other lets see

Comment: yes i got it.. actually i installed on my real phone and on the emulator. i got the message on my phone immediately and on emulator after 3-4 minutes